# Api de mercadopago no despliega opcion de cuotas

Tags: mercadopago

instale un botón de pagos (basic checkout) de mercadopago en mi pagina todavia sigo utilizando las opciones de testeo (2 usuarios de prueba), esto se debe a que no logro hacer funcionar las cuotas. Le seteo el parámetro de las cuotas (Siempre un int de valor 3,6,9 o 12) pero solo me da la opción a 1. En la documentación solo se especifica que hay que setear el campo installments por lo que no entiendo si el error es porque es un usuario de prueba o si yo estoy haciendo algo mal.

```
$preference_data = array(
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "title" => "Membresía Pro-". $post_id,
                        "currency_id" => "UYU",
                        "category_id" => "virtual_goods",
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "unit_price" => floatval($amount * $duration),

                    )
                ),
                 "payment_methods"=> array(
                    "installments"=> intval($duration),
                ),
                "back_urls" => array(
                        "success" => $success_url,
                        "pending" => $pending_url,
                        "failure" => $failure_url,             
                ),
                "additional_info" => $post_id,
                "notification_url" => $notificacion_url,


            );
```

Desde ya gracias,
Felipe

Answer (score 0):

Verifica de NO tener installments y default_installments dentro de los metodos de pago cuando creas las preferencias, Ya que esto limita solo al pago en una cuota:

```
    "payment_methods": {
        "installments": 1,
        "default_installments": 1,
    },
```

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), Ramiro. Tu respuesta puede tener la intención de solucionar la inquietud, pero para que cumpla correctamente su objetivo debes estructurarla mejor, incluir alguna explicación que facilite el entendimiento de tu propuesta y poner enlaces que referencien algún artículo que complementen tu respuesta. Te invito a leer este artículo [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).